# Simple C++ GUI Toolkit

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, user-interface, toolkit

I'm looking for a nice and simple GUI Toolkit that I can use with MSVC++ 2008.  I need something with simple examples/tutorials and good documentation.

I've already tried wxWidgets, and I had a real headache on trying to compile it.  And the Qt tutorials and examples seem way to complicated for me.

I have quite a bit experience in Swing, it's been the only GUI toolkit that I've been able to understand.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Three years ago I was very young and foolish and didn't know that much about widgeting toolkits.  It'd highly recommend using Qt now.  It's been working very well for me.

Comment: Qt really is very simple, once you get their way of doing things. And the documentation is excellent. Far better than most other toolkits I've worked with. If I were you, I'd definitively invest some more time trying to understand Qt. Once you get it, it's really simple and consistent.

Comment: I second the "Qt really is very simple" view. In either case, the best part of Qt for me is that the documentation is remarkably good both in completeness and readability.

Comment: Try the tutorial from Qt 4.4.  It's easier for a complete beginner than the later ones.  http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.4/tutorials-tutorial.html

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason that MFC, the toolkit that ships with MSVC++, is not an option for you?  There's tons of example code and it's not particularly difficult to work with.

Comment: Programming MFC feels very unlike programming C++. The design pattern isn't suitable for a large group -- that's why M$ develops .net I think.

Comment: We have a fairly large group (30+ people) working on a single MFC application, and it works fine.  Can't comment on the feel -- not enough experience with other packages for comparison.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/)? I haven't used it that much myself and it's not particularly popular, but it's a relatively simple library with decent documentation. There's also [GTKmm](http://gtkmm.org), which is quite a bit more complicated, but much more widely used.

Answer (score 2):

Uh, if Qt looks complicated.. anyway, try [fltk](http://www.fltk.org/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Visual C++ then why not just use the built in MFC widgets? It comes with an extensively-supported visual form designer integrated into the IDE, right? You drag and drop components from a toolbox and set properties from a graphical list; it can't possibly be easier.

Comment: Eh, I don't really like GUI Designers, I find it more fun to type up everything.

Comment: I was also about to suggest it as the simplest way. The only thing he needs to get familiarized with is how to call unmanaged C++ code from clr application.

Comment: @Benjamin -- you asked for the simple way, and this is the simplest one.

Comment: @Gene I thought that Visual C++ 2008 (different from Visual Studio 2008) let you design forms on MFC in normal C++ without being in .NET.

Comment: @Brian -- I didn't notice you suggested MFC. Yes, it's still there, but using built-in designer is even simpler, except one need to remember how to marshal strings to unmanaged code and back.

Comment: @Brian: I'm not sure what distinction you're trying to make between VC++ and VS. VS is the IDE that's included in VC++ (among other things). And yes, it does let you drag and drop controls on forms and compile them to native applications.

Comment: @Jerry OK, for some reason I was under the impression that Visual C++ for Windows was a different product from Visual Studio for C++/CLI

Comment: @Brian: yes and no. They include different compilers, but the IDE is the same (though its default configuration may be different between the two).